# Calling methods with Node/Expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, http, get, controller

I have a controller that has a method that uses GET to return an object (json format). I want to call it from another controller.

In order to make it easier to understand, let's call the controllers controllerSrc (source) and controllerTgt (target).

First, I import the controller and instantiate the variable of the method.

```
const controllerSrc = require('controllerSrc')

const controllerSrcGET= controllerSrc.get
```

In theory, the controllerSrcGET returns a json object, so when I try to do:

`console.log(controlerSrcGET._id)`

I should have there the id of the object and work arount it. However, I get undefined.

**Extra info**

I am working with Morgan, and I've noticed that the GET request that should be printed is not. So I'm guessing that it is not enough to instantiate the controllerSrcGET(?)

Comment: Isn't `controllerSrcGET` a function that should be called like this `console.log(controlerSrcGET()._id)`?

Comment: @Anatoly It was one of the issues! However it doesn't solve it all :( I do something like this in the called controller: const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]. I'm told that headers is not known. I think it's something related to the routes tho

Comment: @Anatoly The main method is executed because we're in its route. However, when it calls the other method, as we're not in its route is not being executed. I'm not sure how to make it work

Comment: The best thing you can do is to extract all the common code that will be used by both controllers to a separate module and not to try to call one controller in another controller. That's not how it should work.